# What are the search limits of factors of the numbers $10^{2^n}+1$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, reference-request, prime-factorization

For the Fermat numbers, I know such a site which shows how far the factors of $2^{2^n}+1$ have been searched.

> Is there somewhere a survey for the search limits for factors of the numbers $10^{2^n}+1$ ?

Comment: Just purely out of curiosity: why $10$ in particular (as opposed to any other base)? It's not particularly important, I'm merely curious.

Comment: Numbers of the form $1000...0001$ (in decimal expansion) appear to be the most interesting generalized Fermat numbers for me. In particular, the decimal expansion can easily be described.

Comment: Another question that would interest me : Which is the smallest $n$ for which it is unknown whether $10^{2^n}+1$ is prime ?

Comment: @Peter See sequences [A275381](https://oeis.org/A275381) and [A080176](https://oeis.org/A080176).

Comment: @DmitryEzhov Those entries do not help much here. Moreover, I hate OEIS because they always beg for donations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Prothsearch](http://www.prothsearch.com) provides a [factoring status](http://www.prothsearch.com/GFN10.html) for generalized Fermat numbers $10^{2^{n}}+1$.

It is also mentioned at the bottom of the page the smallest $n=31$ for which it is not known if $10^{2^{n}}+1$ is prime or composite.

Finally the [search limits of GFN factors](http://www.prothsearch.com/GFNsrch.txt).

$$ $$

**Edit:** I have finished primality tests for $n=24$ and $n=25$ , 
done with [LLR by Jean Penné](http://jpenne.free.fr/index2.html). Results:

$\large 10^{2^{24}}+1$ is not prime, thus composite with no known factors.

$\large 10^{2^{25}}+1$ is not prime, thus composite with no known factors.

Comment: for $n=24$ a primaltiy test with [PFGW](https://sourceforge.net/projects/openpfgw/)  [N-1, Brillhart-Lehmer-Selfridge] would take approximately 7 days on a single core CPU. I'm courious if someone has tested so far. for $n=25$ the test would take about a month. So we get a 'small' chance finding a 16 respectively 33 million digit prime. Let's do it :)

Comment: Perfect ! (+1 and accept) . I only do not quite understand the last link. I guess the factors have been searched upto some limit base $b$ upto the given $k$

Comment: In the second case, you would find a new record prime ! Good luck !