# Is $10^{2^n}+1$ always composite for $n\geq 2$?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

> Is $10^{2^n}+1$ always composite for $n\geq 2$?

I've tried a couple of things, including testing $\phi(10^{2^n}+1)\stackrel{?}{=}10^{2^n}$ and trying to algebraically factor, but I'm not quite able to nail it down.

I've used my computer to factor them, and it seems true up to $2\leq n\leq 8$.

I've read [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3751967/is-22m-21-always-a-composite-number-for-m2?rq=1), and the same method seems promising but doesn't quite pan out.

Comment: Sounds a lot like the question for Fermat numbers from $2^{2^5}+1$ onwards.

Comment: The only know primes are when $n=0$ and $n=1$ ($11$ and $101$).  The $n=14$ case has a smallest prime factor of $1702047085242613845984907230501142529$

Comment: See also [What are the search limits of factors of the numbers $10^{2^n}+1$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3267337/what-are-the-search-limits-of-factors-of-the-numbers-102n1?noredirect=1)

Comment: See also: Bjorn & Reisel: [Factors of generalized Fermat numbers, 1998](https://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1998-67-221/S0025-5718-98-00891-6/S0025-5718-98-00891-6.pdf)